# How can I add ip-based rate limits with longer intervals on API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf

I have an API Gateway endpoint that I would like to limit access to. For anonymous users, I would like to set both daily and monthly limits (based on IP address).

AWS WAF has the ability to set rate limits, but the interval for them is a fixed 5 minutes, which is not useful in this situation.

API Gateway has the ability to add usage plans with longer term rate quotas that would suit my needs, but unfortunately they seem to be based on API keys, and I don't see a way to do it by IP.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do using AWS Services?
Is it maybe possible to use a usage plan and automatically generate an api key for each user who wants to access the api? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Without more context on your specific use-case, or the architecture of your system, it is difficult to give a “best practice” answer.

Like most things tech, there are a few ways you could accomplish this. One way would be to use a combination of CloudWatch API logging, Lambda, DynamoDB (with Streams) and WAF.

At a high level (and regardless of this specific need) I’d protect my API using WAF and the AWS security automations quickstart, [found here](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/aws-waf-security-automations/), and associate it with my API Gateway as guided in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html). Once my WAF is setup and associated with my API Gateway, I’d enable CloudWatch API logging for API Gateway, as discussed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html). Now that I have things setup, I’d create two Lambdas.

The first will parse the CloudWatch API logs and write the data I’m interested in (IP address and request time) to a DynamoDB table. To avoid unnecessary storage costs, I’d set the TTL on the record I’m writing to my DynamoDB table to be twice whatever my analysis’s temporal metric is... ie If I’m looking to limit it to 1000 requests per 1 month, I’d set the TTL on my DynamoDB record to be 2 months. From there, my CloudWatch API log group will have a subscription filter that sends log data to this Lambda, as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample).

My second Lambda is going to be doing the actual analysis and handling what happens when my metric is exceeded. This Lambda is going to be triggered by the write event to my DynamoDB table, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html). I can have this Lambda run whatever analysis I want, but I’m going to assume that I want to limit access to 1000 requests per month for a given IP. When the new DynamoDB item triggers my Lambda, the Lambda is going to query the DynamoDB table for all records that were created in the preceding month from that moment, and that contain the IP address. If the number of records returned is less than or equal to 1000, it is going to do nothing. If it exceeds 1000 then the Lambda is going to update the WAF [WebACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateWebACL.html), and specifically [UpdateIPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateIPSet.html) to reject traffic for that IP, and that’s it. Pretty simple.

With the above process I have near real-time monitoring of request to my API gateway, in a very efficient, cost-effective, scaleable manner in a way that can be deployed entirely Serverless.

This is just one way to handle this, there are definitely other ways you could accomplish this with say Kinesis and Elastic Search, or instead of logs you could analyze CloudTail events, or by using a third party solution that integrates with AWS, or something else.